# Why anchor not showing after adding social media share links

Tags: html, hyperlink, laravel-blade, laravel-9

I am working on a Laravel application and trying to add social share options. But bellow codes are not working and tag not showing!

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u={{ route('single-course', $course->slug) }}" target="_blank" class="facebook"><i class="fa-brands fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
<a href='https://twitter.com/share?url={{ route('single-course', $course->slug) }}' target="_blank" class="twitter"><i class="fa-brands fa-twitter"></i></a>
```

Bellow codes are also not working and anchor tag become hidden!

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=https://www.google.com" target="_blank" class="facebook"><i class="fa-brands fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
<a href='https://twitter.com/share?url=https://www.google.com/' target="_blank" class="twitter"><i class="fa-brands fa-twitter"></i></a>
```

Comment: I found the solution of this problem. My ad blocker was refusing them. I don't know why!

Answer (score 1):

The text inserted in between will be displayed as a link. You have inserted nothing. So, the link seems like hidden

```
<a>Insert some text here</a>

<a><i>In your case,insert some text here to display</i></a>
```

Comment: But I'm using fontawesome icons by '<i></i>' tag

Answer (score 1):

1. The icons have correct height or width? By default, the anchor element
   takes the size from its content.
2. Are the fontawesome icons correctly added to your page? Maybe the CDN is missing...

Comment: Everything working greatly. Also Mozilla Firefox browser showing tag!

Comment: Are the routes url_encoded?

Comment: No. They are not url_encoded.

Comment: Thanks for your kind response. It is working now. My ad blocker was refusing them. I don't know why!